# Store remote server credentials when using MySQL federated tables in a centralized and secure way

Tags: mysql, credentials, federated-table

I would like to use MySQL federated tables as described in the documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-use.html

However, I would not like to have to repeat the remote server credentials with the password in the clear for each table.

Is there a way to use the same credentials for all federated tables? And to store this credentials in a secure way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this answer on dba.stackexchange.com can answer this one: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10850/any-disadvantages-to-enabling-federated-storage-engine

I'll confirm that it works in my scenario